# Advice for calculating the forces for two shafts where one is inside the other

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

Im trying to design a 2 step gear transmission where the idea is to have the input shaft inside a hollow output shaft. Im in doubt how the bearing forces are calculated to determine bearing life. My initial idea is that radial forces from the input shaft would superpose on the output shaft. This seems really simple though. Is there more to it? Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how the shafts will be connected and positions of bearings?